# FloatingActionButton doesn't change in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, floating-action-button

My floating action button looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjhOA.png)

It should show a plus icon in it.

My code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.tasks.TasksFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_tasks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add_task"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:src` try with `app:srcCompat`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add_task"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```